# Actions on Google: HTTP POST User Entities v2

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm looking to create an User Entity for each user.

Using this url from the docs:
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/{parent=projects/*/agent/sessions/*}/entityTypes

And POST body of:

```
{
  "name": myString,
  "entityOverrideMode": enum(EntityOverrideMode),
  "entities": [
    {

      {
        "value": "myHistory",
        "synonyms": [
          "history",
          "Google\u0027s history",
          "past",
          "Google\u0027s past",
          "history of Google"
        ]
      }   
    }
  ]
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

I've inserted this code in my NodeJS server, but ERROR says enum is a reserve keyword.

update 17 may:
    request.post(
          link,

```
  {
    "name": entityname,
    "entityOverrideMode": ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT,
    "entities": [
      {

              "value": "barbie",
              "synonyms": [
                "barbie",
                "barbiedoll",
                "barb",
                "barbie\u0027s doll",
                "doll"
              ]

      }
    ]
  },
      function (error, response, body) {
          if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
              console.log(body)
          }
      }
  );
```

where link is 'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/' + conv.body.session + '/entityTypes';

and entityname = conv.body.session + '/entityTypes/device_name'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enum is a reserved keyword in ES5 and ES6.

The **enum(EntitiyOverrideMode)** here means that this value should be any of the EntitiyOverrideMode enum values provided in the reference [here.](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes#SessionEntityType.EntityOverrideMode)

Comment: Hi @Taylor Caldwell, 

i've used "entityOverrideMode": ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT in my POST request but firebase threw an error 'ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT is not defined'. Am I supposed to put this as a string?

Comment: Yes, to be valid JSON, it must be a String value.

Comment: Yes that is right. I have this error printed out now:  body: '{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 401,\n    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",\n    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"\n  }\n}\n' }